# Equivalent of an Octave command in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I'm trying to realise the following Octave command in MATLAB:

```
M = eye(x)(y,:);
```

`x` is just a number (in my example `10`) and `y` is a vector (here 8x1):

```
y = [1 3 4 5 7 10 9 10];
```

The Octave command would generate:

```
M =

   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    
   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    
   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0    
   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0    
   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0    
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1    
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0    
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

The ones are kept very near to the diagonal.

The nearest I came with MATLAB is with the following commands:

```
n = size(y,1);
Y = eye(n, x);
```

but it would generate something still different. If the difference between rows and columns gets bigger, it would be very different.

```
M =

   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
```

How could I get the first matrix with MATLAB?

Comment: The 6th row of your first M array is awkward... do you confirm?

Comment: You can't chain indices like that in MATLAB, you have to put `eye(x)` in a temp variable.

Comment: Could you provide an example please, beaker?

Comment: What beaker meant: `M = eye(x);` ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  `M= M(y,:);`

Comment: I would suggest you to read your error message: `()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.`

Comment: The duplicate target I linked shows you some of the approaches if you're interested. However the simplest (and the best) way is to use a temporary variable.

Answer (score 0):

First you should find what this expression `eye(x)(y,:)` means. First create an identity matrix with the size of `x` by `x`, and then select rows with index in `y`. Therefore, the equivalent syntax would be:

```
 E = eye(x);
 M = E(y,:);
```